# Phing 2.4.5 ReflexiveTask exits on some servers

Tags: php, deployment, phing

When performing a phing process to certain servers, the phing task exits after performing a reflexiveTask with filterChain even though instructions continue. No error is thrown, phing just cleanly terminates.

On another computer, the same phing-target executes correctly and does execute the consecutive instructions.

Both computers are running phing 2.4.5 (stable) yet the results are different. Does DbDeploy have other dependencies in the pear packages?

Anyone have any other ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT: Link to phing bug-tracker ticket: http://bit.ly/ipHMki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the ticket has been closed. I identified the error being caused by the reflective task (with the filter chains) were attempting to process large PDF files. This caused PHP to hit its memory limit so, to fix, I am only processing certain files now:

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
<reflexive>
  <fileset dir=".">
    <include pattern="**/*.php">
    <include pattern="**/*.ini">
     ...
  </fileset>
</reflexive> 
...
```

It appears that the reflexiveTask uses more memory than the copyTask. Something to keep in mind if switching between the two like I was doing.